# Timer is not Running while edit the app in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I am starting Timer on App `OnStart` Event and pauses automatically after 10 seconds, it works perfectly when I run the app but in editing mode the Timer is not starting.

I have set one variable on Start property of timer and made it as true in `Onstart` event of the app.

Is there any way to start the timer in Edit mode of PowerApps?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [similar issue](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Timers-in-edit-mode/td-p/597528):

It is a [known limitation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-timer) that in PowerApps studio Timer runs only in Preview mode. It is not supported to run it in Edit mode.